# Firefox Images flicker when loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sure this has been answered a few times but I've searched the website and couldn't find a solution.

My images are quite high resolute that have been scaled down to a size set in my HTML 5 document (not in CSS) was just wondering if there is a permanent solution for this? Noticed the issue isn't present in Chrome.

Comment: is the "flicker" happening if you actually use the scaled down image and not the browser scale it down?

Comment: It still happens yeah its mostly present towards the bottom of the image the flicker is quite noticeable.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle of it. You can use imgur.com to host the image.